# Asp.net web user control as bootstrap modal

Tags: asp.net

I have a user control that mut act as modal - so this web control popups great as a modal but the linkbutton click event is not triggered. 
- On click of the link button in the modal ( web user control ) it just closes the modal pop.

The code that opens a modal popup in page ( works fine ):

```
protected void lbChatMessage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{         
    Control row = LoadControl("~/uc/page_chat_message.ascx");
    ((uc.page_chat_message)row).ID = "MessagePlugin";            
    phChatMessage.Controls.Add(row);
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "ChatModalScript", "$('#chat').modal('show');", true);
}
```

The link button click in the modal ( web user control ) - it does not work
 - I also put that AJAX `UpdatePanel` in the `usercontrol`:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 text-right">                                       
    <asp:LinkButton ID="ButtonSendMessage" CssClass="btn bg-teal-400 btn-labeled btn-labeled-right" runat="server" onclick="ButtonSendMessage_Click">
        <b> <i class="icon-circle-right2"> </i> </b> 
        Send
    </asp:LinkButton>
</div>
```

Server-side of the web user control:

```
protected void ButtonSendMessage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

this button event does not get triggered

What am I doing doing wrong as this sendmessage linkbutton doesnt work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are adding the User Control doesn't add the Control to the Page's ViewState.

**What's happening:**

The `ButtonSendMessage_Click` triggers a post_back back to the server, but the server has no reference to that control in the Page's ViewState so that the event isn't registered.

**What you need to do:**

Instead of adding the control in the `lbChatMessage_Click` event, you should have the control already added to your page but hidden.  Then use Javascript only to show that popup on button click rather than doing a postback.  That way your modal is registered with ViewState and the `ButtonSendMessage_Click` will then fire correctly.

Comment: I have made changes as you suggested - and button click event gets triggered now. THANK YOU...
The only problem that I'm facing now is -  when the SendMessage button event gets executed the modal form( user control ) just vanish ( and leave the screen on modal state overlay view( with no modal form showing) )

ANY idea what is that?

Comment: Yes, because SendMessage does a full postback which redraws the page - You can explicitly make the modal visible in the SendMessage method as well to get around this. Please mark as answer if you were satisfied with my responses.

Comment: Yeah you right the page postback is a problem.
Thanks a lot for your help.